# Output prediction when predictors amplify each other

Tags: neural-networks, prediction

I hope the title is clear as I couldn't explain my problem better.

I'm new to Neural networks and trying to create a model to predict the general situation of a specific market (e.g strong market/weak market,...).
I think in reality what I'm working on - while similar to it - is not a neural network since I don't want to have the typical structure of a network (input, hidden layer, output) mainly because the input(s) I have in mind are extremely general (like political situation or general economy) and I can't provide the network with a significant training set. Instead I tried to identify and map all the nodes between the stimuli and the final parameter I want to predict.
In this way I have a pseudo-NN which I can assign weights to it and whenever I get some data about any node(a value), try to predict its effect on the final parameter. 
My problem is, unlike a feedforward NN, some of the nodes may amplify each other. For example Increasing A, increases B and Increasing B increases A even more. Could you suggest any model/ Architecture suite for this problem? I afraid using NN was completely wrong to begin with.

[image: pseudo-NN map]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with neural nets, it sounds like you may be interested in [rnn](/questions/tagged/rnn) structures because they incorporate feedback loops in the network topology.

Alternatively, [graph algebra](https://us.sagepub.com/en-us/nam/graph-algebra/book229733) is a social science tool that can be used to express complex models incorporating things like feedback loops. I think this might be closer to what you're actually interested in, instead of neural networks because (1) you already have a notion of what you want to model, and how the various factors are related and (2) you're modeling social phenomena, so the graph algebra literature will be written with your goal in mind.

Two key publications:

- Brown, Courtney (2008), *Graph Algebra: Mathematical Modeling With a Systems Approach*, Quantitative Applications in the Social Sciences, 151, SAGE, ISBN 9781412941099.
- Cortés, Fernando, Adam Przeworski, and John Sprague. 1974. *Systems Analysis for Social Scientists.* New York: John Wiley & Sons.